# Test Client can not connect to WCF Service self-hosted in winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I have a WCF Service self-hosted in a winforms application. I used the following links:

- [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx)
- [How to: Publish Metadata for a Service Using Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738489.aspx)

When I use the WCF Test Client and try to add service I get the following error:
Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

Error Details:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:8001/HelloWorld If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
>
> For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:8001/HelloWorld
>
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8001/HelloWorld'.
>
> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8001/HelloWorld that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> Unable to connect to the remote server    No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8001HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:8001/HelloWorld
>
> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8001/HelloWorld'.
>
> Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8001

Here is my Code:

```
public Server()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    using (host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), new Uri("http://localhost:8001/HelloWorld")))
    {
        // Check to see if the service host already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        // If not, add one
        if (smb == null)
            smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        //You need to add a metadata exchange (mex) endpoint to your service to get metadata.
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

        //http
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorldService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");

        host.Open();
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello(string name);
}

public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    public string SayHello(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: @jskiles1 I turned off windows firewall. Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but switching the using(){} to a try{}..catch{} allows this code to function properly. The WCF Test Client can successfully add the service and I can browse to the running service via: http://localhost:8001/HelloWorld

Comment: It's because using ends up disposing your service. Add `Console.ReadLIne()` or anything similar to pause the execution after `host.Open()` and it will work even with `using`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the root cause is down at the bottom:

> Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8001

I would check your event log to see if the host.Open() call is failing (perhaps due to a firewall or something) or walk through it with your debugger then use telnet to see if it is actually listening on 8001.

Comment: I ran the program and tried using telnet. "telnet 127.0.0.1 8001". I am receiving "Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to host on port 8001: Connect failed". I turned of windows firewall while testing this. When stepping through the code with the debugger, host.open() does not throw an exception...

Comment: Do you mean the windows event viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is The Solution for it 
Try This it will Work

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8001/HelloWorld");

    // Create the ServiceHost.
    using (serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
    {
        // Enable metadata publishing.
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
        // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
        // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
        // by the service.
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorldService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
        serviceHost.Open();

    }
```